accessing properties using keyof in typescript
Not sure why typescript is complaining here
type ObjectWithMatchingProperties<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};

type MainState = {
  selectedProduction: {
    eventName: string
  }
  activePricingGroup: {
    name: string
  }
}
type MainStateObj = ObjectWithMatchingProperties<MainState>
type InventoryState = {
  mainSlice: MainStateObj;
};

const state: InventoryState = {
  mainSlice: {
    selectedProduction: {
      eventName: 'test',
    },
    activePricingGroup: {
      name: 'act',
    }
}};

export const useMainInventoryStore = (key: keyof MainState) => state.mainSlice[key]

const selectedProduction = useMainInventoryStore('selectedProduction');
// error at this line:
selectedProduction.eventName


The code Errors out with

Property 'eventName' does not exist on type '(state: InventoryState) => { eventName: string; } | { name: string; }'.

Here is the playgroud

Why aren't you calling selectedProduction as a function? Do you really mean to index into it that way, or is that just a typo? You've got two essentially unrelated problems. One is this confusion about functions (which feels like something you should just fix in the question itself), the other is the fact that you probably want useMainInventoryStore to be generic in the type of key, which looks like this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so, please [edit] to make your question about just one of those issues and we'll proceed.

thx @jcalz this line did the trick export const useMainInventoryStore = <K extends keyof MainState>(key: K) =>   ((state: InventoryState) => state.mainSlice[key]); pls answer the question below and I'll mark as resolved! thx man!
ps: I've updated the original question with your suggestions

Your useMainInventoryStore function's return type does not depend on its input. Since the input is the union type keyof MainState, then the output is the corresponding union type { eventName: string; } | { name: string; }. Even if you call it with "selectedProduction" as the input, the output is a union type, and TypeScript has no idea whether it will have an eventName property or a name property.  And so it complains if you try to index into it with either key (see Typescript property does not exist on union type).

If you'd like the function's output type to depend on the input type, you should make it a generic function, like this:
const useMainInventoryStore =
  <K extends keyof MainState>(key: K) => state.mainSlice[key]

Now the input is of generic type K which is constrained to keyof MainState.  And thus the output is of the generic type ObjectWithMatchingProperties<MainState>[K], a generic indexed access type corresponding to whatever property exists at state.mainSlice[key].
And now when you call the function the output type reflects the type of the input:
const selectedProduction = useMainInventoryStore('selectedProduction')
// const selectedProduction: {eventName: string;}

And you can index into it:
selectedProduction.eventName // okay

Playground link to code

perfect answer with very detailed explanation! Thank you @jcalz!

Your useMainInventoryStore returns another function. Did you forget to apply it to some state argument?

I did what you are suggesting, and it's the same error..
`const state: InventoryState = {mainSlice: {
selectedProduction: {
eventName: 'test',
},
activePricingGroup: {
name: 'act',
}
}};
export const useMainInventoryStore = (key: keyof MainState) =>  state.mainSlice[key];
const selectedProduction = useMainInventoryStore('selectedProduction')
selectedProduction.eventName`

That's a different issue though, since "this function doesn't have a eventName prop" is an error you should expect to see, while "this union of things, one of which has an eventName prop, doesn't have an eventName prop" might be more reasonably unexpected.
